# SocketChannel connect takes long time

Tags: android

```
SocketChannel sockChannel = SocketChannel.open();
sockChannel.configureBlocking(false);
sockChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(remoteAddr, remotePort));
```

Connect is taking 30ms to 50ms sometimes more than 100ms on Android
version 2.3.4 and 3.2.1.
I have executed several tests on two hardwares and it is always that
slow. I was hoping that it takes less than 2-3 ms since it is non-
blocking.

Is this a known issue ?
I am using Selector to select over the 10s of SocketChannels for
SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT. Selector.select uses a timeout of 100ms in
this case but overall time taken is more than 1 second which is mostly
because of the SocketChannel.connect. Is there any alternative to
avoid the problem of SocketChannel.connect and still achieve to finish
the selector in 100ms.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why a socket connection could be slow: server overload, device with a poor internet connection, and so many other factors. Don't forget, you're connecting to a server over the internet; it's not physically possible for it to be completely instantaneous.

Comment: 1) Same code works way faster on emulator.

Comment: Same code takes less than 1 milliseconds on Linux as well as ICS 4.0.3.

Comment: There is no internet or server load issue here as described in the comments above. Also, Connect is supposed to be non blocking here and at worst it could send a TCP SYN and nothing much more it should be doing to be blocking for so many milliseconds as it is supposed to be NON-BLOCKING the way it is in other cases as described in above comments.

Answer (score 0):

If `remoteAddr` is a `String`, a (blocking) attempt will be made to resolve that name into an `InetAddress`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#InetSocketAddress%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

30 to 100 ms sounds like a reasonable round trip time for a DNS query.

That means, the delay occurs before `connect()` is even called.

Comment: remoteAddr is INetAddress which was created from byte array by calling getByAddress.

Comment: Is the android device under some sort of load? If so, it might simply take the time until the thread gets CPU cycles - especially if it's a single-core device and/or has a low CPU clock and other threads / apps do stuff at the same time. However, that's speculation.